# A triangle has an area of $12$ in$^2$, and two of the sides of the triangle have lengths $5 in.$ and $7 in$

Tags: trigonometry

A triangle has an area of $12$ in$^2$, and two of the sides of the triangle have lengths $5 in.$ and $7 in$. Find the angle included by these two sides. (Assume the angle is acute)

How do I do this??

Comment: Area $=\frac12 ab\sin C$.

Comment: Is it ~43.3 degrees?

Comment: Yes.${}{}{}{}{}$

Answer (score 1):

Let the included angle be $\theta$. If $7$ in is viewed as the base of the triangle, then the height of the triangle is $(5\sin\theta)$ in.

$$\begin{align*}
\frac12 \cdot 7\cdot 5\sin\theta &= 12\\
\sin\theta&=\frac{24}{35}\\
\theta&=\sin^{-1}\frac{24}{35}\\
\end{align*}$$